# C++ Templated linked list getting data element of a complex data type

Tags: c++

I've been working on updating my old templated linked list to be able to take a complex data type. But I have no idea how to make it be able to return the data element in the node class. Currently the code for my node class looks like this:

```
using namespace std;

#ifndef Node_A
#define Node_A

template <class T>
class Node
{
public:
    Node();
    ~Node();
    T getData();
    Node* getNext();
    void setData(T);
    void setNext(Node*);

private:
    Node *next;
    T data;
};

template <class T>
Node<T>::Node()
{
    next = NULL;
    return;
}

template <class T>
Node<T>::~Node()
{
    return;
}

template <class T>
T Node<T>::getData()
{
    return data;
}

template <class T>
Node<T>* Node<T>::getNext()
{
    return next;
}

template <class T>
void Node<T>::setData(T a)
{
    data = a;
    return;
}

template <class T>
void Node<T>::setNext(Node* a)
{
    next = a;
    return;
}

#endif
```

Now this works perfectly fine if the data type T is a primitive but if you use a non-primitive like say a struct it would give a runtime error. I presume because structs don't do operator overloading for = operator. Is there a simple way of fixing this without completely overhauling the class?

Comment: Do you want to copy elements in by value, or do you just want pointers to the elements in your linked list?

Comment: good point. Ultimately the list class has to implement some sort of search that will use getData to compare the data in list class to the element retrieved from the node class. I want all the processing of the linked list to be done outside of main in either list or node class. But to manipulate say a struct I would need some information about its' structure which I can't know before the main creates an instance of it. Unless I'm missing some higher level coding strategies.

Comment: This: `Node<T>::Node()` shouldn't even be an option. What point is there in constructing a node that has contains templates data if all you're doing is default constructing that data? The *usage* of this node template within your linked list should be rather revealing as to what you need and what you don't. And regarding the assignment operator, unless the type T or one of its members is specifically *not* assignable, This should work. You may, however, want to employ move semantics to cut down on all the unnecessary copying. Regardless, how about posting code that **reproduces the problem**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not about overloading the = operator, it's about implementing the assignment operator for the struct. If you do that, you won't need to change your `Node` class, unless I've missed something else.

The above assumes that you'll be making copies of the data inside the Node. Alternatively, you can pass the data by reference. In this case, you need to be careful that the data doesn't get deleted before the Node object is deleted, otherwise you'll get a crash when trying to access a deleted data object from your Node.